# Unable to successfully boot to the desktop after forced shutdown

Tags: raspberry-pi, read-only, raspbian, fsck, job-control

I am running Raspbian Wheezy. Since yesterday I was unable to boot my RPi after a forced shutdown (unplugging the power chord). Since then it starts as follows: http://pastebin.com/QiEbda2y

Note the next few lines:

```
  [    2.176606] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) readonly on device 179:2.
...
  [    2.220626] Starting init: /etc/init exists but couldn't execute it (error -13)
```

It then starts sh. When I try to run bash, it gives the following warnings:

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
root@(none):/#
```

Note that it said `root@(none)`

Also, (somewhat expected) the boot drive isn't mounted and (completely not expected) the root drive is in read-only mode. I am able to mount those both in rw mode with:

```
fsck /dev/mmcblk0p1 (needed because dirty bit is set)
mount /boot
mount -o remount,rw /
```

When I run ps, it tells me to run `mount -t proc proc /proc`. This is also needed to use ifup/ifdown.

If I don't use ifdown/ifup on eth0, my ifconfig is empty, but just using ifup makes it complain that eth0 is already up.

I can start the ssh service using `service ssh start` and it is accessible after the previous eth0 setup.

programs like vim still work, but things like `shutdown -r now` didn't work as shutdown wasn't recognized (where it was before). Typing `exit` gives errors (not when exiting from bash, but from the sh, which is pid 1):

```
 Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=00000800
...
```

After that I changed the cmdline.txt to run a root partition on the usb drive `/dev/sda2`(wasn't plugged in the first time I encountered the problem, it was plugged in the time I copied dmesg to the pastebin). The usb was created to contain the Raspbian Jessie. It now worked and the desktop loaded (though the mouse and keyboard stopped working once the desktop was shown) and I could ssh to it without any configuration (apart from changing passwords on the pi and root account)

Changing the cmdline.txt back to /dev/mmcblk0p2 on which the old root was located, and after a proper reboot with `shutdown -r now`, all the old problems persisted, except that I didn't have to fsck the /boot partition.

Before the forced shutdown that caused the issues, I had done about a years worth of apt-get update/upgrade.

Can someone help me to get my raspbian installation back in working condition?

Are there any tools that could help me recover the unknown broken parts of the operating system?

Comment: I think the SD card is deaad :/

Comment: @djsmiley2k no it isn't as the file system is still fully accessible and when the old /boot is on the SD and a clean install of / is on USB, it works just fine

Comment: Is file rescue, rinse and reinstall not an option?

Comment: @Sam3000 that is a last resort option, but I am looking for a solution where I don't have to reinstall.

Comment: Probably got some files corrupt. No choice but @Sam3000.

Comment: Error -13 is "Permission denied" (EACCESS). What are the permissions of /etc/init? Also, I'm confused why it tries to *execute* /etc/init, it should execute `/sbin/init` and look for the configuration in /etc/init. I agree that probably files got corrupted, unless you can pinpoint them, reinstall is easier.

Comment: @dirkt I was hoping to find a tool that can verify my linux distro (using checksums or anything). At the time of questioning I was not able to reinstall because I didn't have another SD card reader (my laptop that I used the first time had died). Now that I do have a new laptop I will try to reinstall (now I only have to find out how to copy over my tomcat server to the new install -_-)

Comment: The are tools to [verify installed packages](http://serverfault.com/questions/322518/can-dpkg-verify-files-from-an-installed-package), but that takes about as long as just reinstalling them, and it doesn't check all files (not all have md5sums).